# Audio/Video out of sync on concatenating videos using ffmpeg : Non-monotonous TDS output

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, format, video-editing, video-encoding

I am trying to add two videos using ffmpeg and the output video/audio is out of sync (and fast forwarded). Goal is to put `intro.mp4`  before the original file `clip.flv`

My approach is to

1. Change the format of `clip.flv` to `clip.mp4`

   ```
   ffmpeg -i clip.flv -q 0 -c copy clip.mp4
   ```
2. Concat `intro.mp4` with `clip.mp4`

   ```
   ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i filesToJoin.txt -c copy combinedvideo.mp4
   ```

   I see this in output log for command#2

   ```
   [mp4 @ 0x3ebcd60] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 392311, current: 391925; changing to 392312. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
   frame= 1566 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=8711kB time=00:00:48.86 bitrate=1460.2kbits/s speed= 272x    
   video:7363kB audio:1294kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.619341%
   ```

---

### Files Metadata

#### Original source file `clip.flv` metadata

```
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:40.09, start: 0.010000, bitrate: 1632 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 1500 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s
```

#### Intermediary file `intro.mp4` metadata

```
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41
    creation_time   : 2020-06-02T10:36:51.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:13.21, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 484 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 130 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30k tbn, 60k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-02T10:36:51.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 317 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2020-06-02T10:36:52.000000Z
      handler_name    : Alias Data Handler
```

#### File `clip.mp4` metadata

```
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:00:40.01, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1635 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 1500 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 16k tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

---

Things I have tried

- As you'll see that the both videos have same frame rate but **different timescale**, I have tried changing the timescale of one of the video to match the other before combining the video but with no luck. For timescale change I used this command

  ```
  ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -video_track_timescale 30000 clip_ts30000.mp4
  ```
- I've had a look at similar questions on SO, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/22941

I think you might need to convert to an intermediate MPEG-TS format and then concatenate those.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am doing now. First converting to .MTS and then converting back to mp4. Are there any drawbacks of this approach?

For me on concat, it worked but on performing more operations(trim and concat again) on the output video reveals that the video has unspecified pixal format and won't let me do those operations

Comment: I unfortunately ran into an insurmountable issue (the concatenated video wouldn't always playback properly on Safari/QuickTime).  Ultimately, I found the only reliable solution was to do an expensive re-transcode.  I might have a different problem from you: I had mismatched resolutions, rather than mismatched timescales.